# MS SQL Server Algebraic Syntax

Tags: sql-server

I have a table logging a floating point value from a scale (a weight). I'd like to evaluate the absolute value of the integral of this curve dynamically. I'm attempting to perform some simple algebra  based on the trapezoidal approx. with a sampling rate (b-a=1) of one:

```
(b-a)((f(a)+f(b))/2 - f(a))
```

The values f(a) and f(b) represent the 2 most recent values logged in my SQL Server table. I've attempted the following with an evalution error:

```
 SELECT TOP 2 
     SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp DESC)/2.0
 FROM table
```

This query evaluates, but simply divides the most recent value by 2:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(ORDER BY t_stamp DESC)/2.0
FROM table
```

As you can see, I haven't even attempted the absolute value or the subtraction of the "2nd most recent" value because I didn't know how to reference a specific row (cell?). As a noob, I feel the math is doable in a single query, I just can't find the proper syntax. Thanks in advance.

So to update more clearly:

Thanks for the input ps2goat, though for some reason I'm unable to implement "TOP" function, so I currently have this:

```
SELECT ABS(SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(PARTITION BY quality_code
    ORDER BY t_stamp
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/2.0)
FROM table
```

Still need to subtract the preceding value, something like:

```
SELECT ABS(SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(PARTITION BY quality_code
    ORDER BY t_stamp
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/2.0
    - 1 PRECEDING)
FROM table
```

Any ideas to reference the preceding value for subtraction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LAG` function to refer to the last value in a certain order. For example:

```
SELECT Scale_Weight AS Current, LAG(Scale_Weight) AS Last OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp)
FROM table
```

You can add your formula tothis query.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.  Instead of timestamps, I used an Identity field, as those are incremented and easier to enter manually (not sure if you had datetime values or actual timestamp values)

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77bcb/4/0

schema:

```
create table x(
  xId int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
  scale_weight decimal(12,4)
  );

insert into x(scale_weight)
 select 24.1234 union all
 select 32.4455 union all
 select 88.1234 union all
 select 223.443;
```

The inner query (below) grabs the top two rows, ordered by id descending (use your `t_stamp` column).  The outer query sums all the `Scale_Weight` values returned by the inner query and divides that value by two.

sql:

```
select SUM(Scale_Weight)/2.0 from
(
  SELECT TOP 2 Scale_Weight      
   FROM x
    ORDER BY xid DESC
  ) y
```

Comment: Thanks for the input ps2goat, though for some reason I'm unable to implement "TOP" function, so I currently have this:

SELECT ABS(SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(PARTITION BY quality_code
 ORDER BY t_stamp
 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/2.0)
FROM table

Still need to subtract the preceding value, something like:

SELECT ABS(SUM(Scale_Weight) OVER(PARTITION BY quality_code
 ORDER BY t_stamp
 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/2.0
        - 1 PRECEDING)
FROM table

Any ideas to reference the preceding value for subtraction?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: I should have included this initially, but I'm using a third party OPC software to generate my tables automatically through their MSSQL translator (I think that's why "TOP" doesn't work). I could get the version, but not sure it would help.

Comment: Would it be easier to subtract the current row? Since I'm using the abs, it shouldn't matter. Can I "Select" the same column twice in a query, i.e., .../2.0 - Scale_Weight OVER(ORDER BY blah, ROWS CURRENT ROW))?

Comment: Maybe, but I prefer fixes over hacks.  Using a third-party table generator would not limit the syntax available when querying.  Are you using a third-party query- or database access- tool?

Comment: Database access tool, but I'm beginning to rethink my query.  I think there's a way of simplifying it by eliminating the time-dependence. Thanks goat (greatest of all time?) and I hope I didn't waste too much of your time.